# Fill in the blank with the correct preposition

Tags: prepositions

The accident took place **_** no fault of his.
This question came on my test and i answered 'due to' but it was marked wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What were the options? That again helps us better.

> The accident took place **through** no fault of his (own?) - sounds okay to me.

*Through* serves here as *due to* or *because*. Check out [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fault).

Comment: There were no options. We just had to fill the blank.